# Django, Postgresql & IntegrityErrors

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I come from a mysql background where if I want to insert a record I can use an INSERT IGNORE command so that I can just bung rows in and if there's a conflict just ignore it.

Now, with a Django project I'm working on I'm using postgresql, and issue multiple saves in a loop.  However, I *think* if I get an IntegrityError (which I'm ignoring, see code below) then I lose loads of objects that I'm trying to insert.. how should I fix this:

```
for thing in things:
    try:
        #potentially dangerous save..
        obj = Thing(stuff=10)
        obj.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

If say, on the 5th go round the loop an IntegrityError happens, which objects will get inserted into the DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will depend on how you manage your transaction.

On Postgres if one of query in transaction fails all subsequent query will also fail with error "current transaction is aborted, queries ignored until end of transaction block".

To deal with it you should use transaction.savepoint_rollback in an except block.

Please refer to Django doc [Handling exceptions within PostgreSQL transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#handling-exceptions-within-postgresql-transactions)

It gives the next example

```
a.save() # Succeeds, and never undone by savepoint rollback
try:
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    b.save() # Could throw exception
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
except IntegrityError:
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
c.save() # Succeeds, and a.save() is never undone
```

Answer (score 1):

By not ignoring errors?

The code you wrote works kind of like this.

```
You:    Save all the things.
Django: You're about to violate data integrity in your database.
You:    I don't care.
Django: I can't simply corrupt your data. I'll just throw away 
        the things that would corrupt your data.
You:    That's what I wanted.
```

While that might be appropriate for some applications, it not appropriate for most.

You just need to decide what you *ought* to be doing with data that violates your integrity constraints, and you need to fix the code that's allowing bad data to get to the save() method in the first place.  Documentation on [Form and Field Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) might help.